# Java 1.4 String.replaceAll issue with single quote

Tags: java, json, string, java1.4, json-simple

I've got a string value coming from a database that has to be put into JSON, but the value can contain single and double quotes. Sounds easy enough, right? Well, apparently not in Java 1.4.2. Don't get me started on why it has to be 1.4.2, I inherited this from another developer and we can't update this project yet due to factors beyond my control. :)

So, I have tried all of these (and lots of others just to see the result):

```
"sample user's string".replaceAll("'", "\'")      // returns "sample user's string"
"sample user's string".replaceAll("'", "\\'")     // returns "sample user's string"
"sample user's string".replaceAll("'", "\\\'")    // returns "sample user's string"
"sample user's string".replaceAll("'", "\\\\'")   // returns "sample user\\'s string"
"sample user's string".replaceAll("'", "%%")      // returns "sample user%%s string"
```

All I want is `sample user\'s string`, what am I doing wrong? Too bad 1.4.2 doesn't have the String.replace(String,String) function.

**Edit**: We are using the `json-simple` JSON library and I was looking at the output of the above commands in the resultant JSON string. I added additional debug info to see the value before the JSON gets output and it looks like the above commands really are working, but the `json-simple` library is stripping the escape chars out.

So, what I'm seeing is:

```
"sample user's string".replaceAll("'", "\\\\'")    // sample user\'s string
myJSONObject.put("value", "sample user's string".replaceAll("'", "\\\\'")) // sample user\\'s string"
myJSONObject.put("value", "sample user's string") // sample user's string
```

So it looks like the library is not doing its job quite as expected. Does anyone that has used `json-simple` know of a workaround for this?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you're looking at the string in a context which is automatically escaping backslashes for you. Your penultimate sample should be fine. For example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("sample user's string".replaceAll("'", "\\\\'"));
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
sample user\'s string
```

You didn't say where you were looking at the value, but if it's in the debugger, that may well be doubling the backslash for you, to present the value as if it were in a Java literal.

Ideally though, you shouldn't be doing this sort of thing manually - it's far too error-prone. You should use a JSON library which handles all of this for you, so you *just* need to specify the value.

Comment: I agree that it shouldn't need to be done manually. We're using the `json-simple` JSON library (the `GSON` library isn't compatible with Java 1.4.2) and without manual escaping, the single quotes aren't getting escaped by the library. Making an edit to the question details to reflect this.

Comment: @Kettch19: How are you diagnosing that the quoting isn't happening? If you're not careful, I can easily see this being a diagnostic issue rather than anything else. Or perhaps json-simple is being smart, and only escaping quotes if it really needs to, e.g. by putting a string which includes single quotes into a double-quoted string, and vice versa.

Comment: I'm looking at the traces via `log4j` output. The `json-simple` call is escaping other characters such as forward slashes, but for some reason is not doing anything for single quotes. And, in fact, unescaping my manual escape sequences when I put them in.

Comment: @Kettch19: Why would it escape *forward* slashes? That sounds very odd. It sounds like you may want to investigate other JSON APIs...

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why...very strange, I'll have to look into that more. This is definitely an issue related to the JSON library and not the JDK as initially thought. Thanks for your help.